# How to push a function into _G (gloal space) in Lua

Tags: lua, global

TLDR; My functions are not callable from the _G scope, and I want them to be so I can call functions by parsing a list of strings. This could be exacerbated by a `package.seeall` required by the framework.

I am working in the luci framework, which is an UCI front end for OpenWRT routers. In an attempt to create customized functions that are called when specific UCI values are parsed I have created functions that share the name of the return value which are called through _G.

The parsed data looks something like this:

```
data = {Name="value"}
```

I code looks like this:

```
function main()
    local pageValues={modules={}}
    for i,x in pairs(data) do
        --here is the part that throws the error
        pageValues.modules[x]=_G[x]()
        --also throws error when "newValue=_G[x]()
    end
end

function value()
--also does not work with "local function value()"
    return 'YEA'
end
```

The error I am getting returned to me is `attempt to call field '?' (a nil value)`
When I directly pass it the string "value" with `pageValues.modules['value']=_G['value']()`I receive `attempt to call field 'value' (a nil value)`
When is create a dummy variable as such

```
dummy = 'value'
pageValues.modules[dummy]=_G[dummy]()
```

I receive `attempt to call field '?' (a nil value)`. This is the same if I use `local dummy = 'value'`

When I parse `_G` to see if any of my functions are in it I find that they are not. **NOTE** Luci automatically calls `package.seeall`, and I don't know if that is what is messing with my global's. But, it may be important in answering this question.

My most urgent need is to get this function running correctly. My secondary interest is in how I can determine the scope in Lua to be able to troubleshot sand-boxing issues in LuCI in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little hard to understand what is going on in your code, since its not a contained executable example, but one thing that could be happening is that, if the module you defined the globals has called the `module` function then whenever you try to set a global it will instead set a key in the module's table. Additionally, if you run module with the package.seeall parameter then global assignments are still redirected - the only difference is that the module can read other predefined global variables.

If this is the case, you would be able to solve your problem by either not trying to read the values from the global table (reading from the appropriate module instead) or by setting `_G` directly when creating those values in the first place.

Comment: Thank you! Looking at the `module` function I saw that it set a scope for the variable. `module("luci.controller.name", package,seeall)` by calling it as such`pageValues.modules[x]=luci.controller.name[x]()` I was able to call my functions as long as they are not declared local.